# Database design decisions

Tags: sql, database, data-modeling

I trying to create an efficient and scalable data model for an application that I am writing. I am coming to a common problem as far as the design goes, the example listed below exemplifies my problem well:

I want to create a table of users each with a primary key ID field, and much like Facebook, they have friends who are also users. would it be better to have a field in the users table called "friends list" that lists all of the IDs of a users friends, or have a table for each user listing all their friends, or maybe some other option I have not though of yet?

I would need to have an efficient way to pull all a users friends information, such as names addresses, etc. But I fear that have a string of IDs that I must iterate through and then join on the users table, might not be terribly efficient especially if I have a partitioned database. This a specific situation, however I see a generalization of this problem elsewhere in my application.

Any help is greatly appreciated.
Thank You!

Comment: You want a separate table that relates one user ID to another.  Do NOT do either of the things you suggested (all the friends in a single column, or separate tables for each user)

Comment: I was contemplating that, however would that table be rather large? for example I have 1500 friends on Facebook, mapping all the relations would mean that join on this table would be inefficient?

Comment: This is what relational databases *do*.  If you are going to use a RDBMS, use its strengths.

Comment: Thanks Joe, Really appreciate it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make a friends tables. This table would have two fields the `User_id` and a `friend_id`(also an `user_id`) Below is a basic image of the design.

[image]

Comment: Can I generate diagrams like the above using eclipse?

Comment: @ReCoNciLiaTiOn, I used dbForge Studio for SQL Server 3.0: http://www.devart.com/dbforge/sql/studio/download.html. I'm not sure if eclipse have a plug-in for making diagrams